# Why running PhpStorm 2021 I got error of lacking memory in my OS?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Working in PhpStorm 2021 I got error of lacking memory in IDE in my Kubuntu 20 (I installed it 3-4 months ago). I ignored it but after restarting I failed to run the OS.

```
$ /opt/PhpStorm-2021.1.4/PhpStorm-211.7628.25/bin/phpstorm.sh
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

I cleared all directories inside of `/home/user/.cache/JetBrains` as I supposed that my cache raised to big size so I cleared space in root of my OS.

I upgraded my OS with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but after restarting I still got the same error.

I have in my OS:

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8067380     1399884     4747912      198804     1919584     6202076
Swap:       2104476           0     2104476

$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
5.11.0-37-generic
x86_64

$ df -HT   
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  4.1G     0  4.1G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     827M  2.1M  825M   1% /run
/dev/sdb2      ext4       53G   28G   23G  55% /           // I HAVE A LOT OF FREE SPACE
tmpfs          tmpfs     4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb7      ext4       30G   13G   16G  44% /var
/dev/sdb1      ext4      339M  208M  106M  67% /boot
/dev/loop0     squashfs  155M  155M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1864
/dev/sdb8      fuseblk   399G  151G  248G  38% /mnt/_work_sdb8
/dev/loop2     squashfs   59M   59M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop1     squashfs  140M  140M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1878
/dev/loop4     squashfs  261M  261M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
/dev/loop7     squashfs   66M   66M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop3     squashfs   59M   59M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop6     squashfs  173M  173M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop5     squashfs  132k  132k     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop8     squashfs   69M   69M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop9     squashfs   69M   69M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop10    squashfs   46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14295
/dev/loop11    squashfs   66M   66M     0 100% /snap/core20/1270
/dev/loop12    squashfs   46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14549
/dev/sda6      fuseblk   237G  122G  115G  52% /mnt/Work_sda6
/dev/sda1      fuseblk    65G   58G  7.2G  89% /mnt/Win_sda1
/dev/sda8      fuseblk   628G  626G  2.7G 100% /mnt/Media_sda8
tmpfs          tmpfs     827M   17k  827M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I found file `/home/user/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.2/phpstorm64.vmoptions`

```
-Xmx984m
-Xms128m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
```

Has it relative options? I tried to modify it (I googled some refs in net) :

```
-Xms5096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:NewSize=1024m
-XX:MaxNewSize=1512m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
```

Restated OS and the same error.

I have a SSD (`sdb` and on Linux partitions are located on it) and HDD (`sda`) on my laptop and I do not use any virtual machines...

What could raise this error and how it can be fixed ?

Comment: If to reinstall phpstorm again, which directories have I to clear firstly?

Comment: Xmx should always be higher than Xms. In your case that's not true. Please try setting the values back to `-Xms128m` and `-Xmx984m`